# How to output log to StackDriver logging in fuelPHP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, fuelphp

I deployed app is created by fuelPHP on GKE.

GKE Cluster is enabled Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring.
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine

But fuelPHP's Log::xxxx() is not output to stackdriver logging.
Then I modified config.php following.

```
//'log_path' =>APPPATH. 'logs',
'log_path' => '/dev/stdout',
```

It's not work.(error occur '/dev/stdout does not exist').

How to output logs to StackDriver logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I override core/Log class as app/Log.

app/classes/log.php

```
<?php

class Log extends \Fuel\Core\Log
{
    public static function initialize()
    {

        //$stream = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($filename, \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
        $stream = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
        $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter("%level_name% - %datetime% --> %message%".PHP_EOL, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $stream->setFormatter($formatter);
        static::$monolog->pushHandler($stream);
    }
}
```

and in app/bootstrap.php.
Add as in the example

```
// Example: 'Log' => APPPATH.'classes/log.php',
```